# Are questions on Kindle Fire on-topic for Android?

Tags: discussion, scope

AFAIK the Kindle Fire runs on a custom version of Android - would questions on these be on-topic when it's released?

(I ask this mainly because because there was a question on Kindle Fire on [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/342720/4377), wanted to know as future reference for migrations as well as future questions that I or anyone else might have)

Comment: too early to say, I think

Comment: Most likely Android devs will root and mod the device to get a more stock (CyanogenMod, etc.) flavor of Android on the device, just like the NookColor. If the device is running such a version of Android, then I would say questions are fair game.  Additionally, it will still run Android apps from the Amazon Market, so it may be fine even as a stock device.

Comment: Since the Fire will run Android apps from the Amazon Market, there likely will be relevant questions, even though the base UI is heavily customized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We already have questions on [google-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-tv) and the [nook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook), just like the Fire both of those devices are running embedded Android that's been heavily modified/hidden.

I can't see why we wouldn't allow Kindle Fire questions as long as they're Android related. Some Fire questions won't be and may be more relevant to Super User or Web Apps, some will be relevant to us.

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting one and hope to be asking questions here.  Bryan and GAThrawn have explained why.

A minor note: Until it's actually released, I expect we won't be accepting questions about it — the only ones we could answer with certitude pertain to the information Amazon has publicly released.  Just like with Ice Cream Sandwich, we won't speculate or post answers that say "go look at this thing Eric Schmidt / Jeff Bezos said"; premature questions generally get closed.

Just something to keep in mind before you migrate :)