# Are Android apps running on Chrome OS on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The main question I have revolve around functionality and is there a way to activate pagedown in Android apps on Chrome OS.

Not sure what people would ask maybe compatibility questions.

Are Android apps running on Chrome OS on topic?  We have to be careful that these don't become a app recommendations questions.

I see there is a Chromebook tag but wanted to make sure.  [This leads me to believe the answer is yes](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/are-questions-on-kindle-fire-on-topic-for-android?rq=1).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe Chrome OS is not Android OS (the meta post you linked is about Android-based OS and it's on-topic here). Meanwhile, Super User has a tag for [google-chrome-os](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome-os). My personal take is:

- If the question is about using Android app only, then it's on-topic on here. Based on my research, [the UI is the same as apps on Android devices](http://www.omgchrome.com/android-apps-notifications-call-alerts-chromebook/), so Android user here can answer it regardless if it's on Chrome OS or not.
- If the question is about operating Chrome OS, then it's more on-topic on [Super User](//superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](//unix.stackexchange.com/) even though it's related to Android apps. The reasoning is, the Android user here doesn't have any idea how to operate Chrome OS. Probably the analogy is like: asking Windows operation on a remote desktop on an Android device; it's on an Android device, but general Android users won't know about Windows operation more than Windows user.

---

I have taken a quick look on [chromebook](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chromebook) tag and I saw questions about interfacing with Chromebook, not about operating Chromebook itself. I also took this chance to clean-up some questions that aren't actually related to Chromebook by removing the tag.