# Acceptability of ChromeOS Questions

Tags: discussion, questions, question-appropriateness

Given the close development relationship with Android I was wondering if ChromeOS questions are acceptable here.

I couldn't see any documentation in the site help specifically prohibiting or allowing questions on this topic so I thought I would get the community's opinion and some sort of consenus.

The other option is that ChromeOS questions are the domain of [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Is it worth me asking on [Meta SuperUser](https://meta.superuser.com/)?

Comment: I think my answer on another meta question kind of answering your concern: [Are Android apps running on Chrome OS on topic?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/are-android-apps-running-on-chrome-os-on-topic/2337#2337|)